# Validating Arrays with Callbacks in Codeigniter

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I'm running an array of user input through form validation utilizing a custom callback as a rule. Each of the submitted data values needs to pass this custom callback. If they don't pass, I want to set a unique error message for whichever values are invalid.

It seems, however, that I can only assign one error message to each rule. What is the best way to assign an error to any value being run through a callback that fails so that each value can maintain its own error?

Comment: My understanding of CI and its form validation library is that the validation is done on a "per field" basis. This may be of interest http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Assosiative_Arrays_via_POST/ but haven't had a proper read of it

Comment: Please provide your code so we can get a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter's form validation allows one message per rule.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the custom error message for that validation rule inside the callback method, before it returns FALSE. example:

```
function _callback($str){
    .... // do validation checks
    $this->form_validation->set_message('_callback', 'Your input ' . $str . 'is not valid');
}
```

This way you still have some flexibility of showing what input string has the error rather than one generic message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a way to completely customize each error and avoid the "one string" problem. I believe I'm going to use the CI Validation to set a general error and then use sessions to set the other errors.

Comment: Using flashdata is also a good idea here if you want to set more specific errors on a case-to-case basis. I use it for one of my apps to set notifications and errors and works like a charm.